# How to select a complete set of products in a shopcart where the youngest product ordered is older than 8 hours

Tags: sql-server

I have a shopcart table with an ordernumber, productid, quantity and orderdate (incl. time) in it.
What I want to achieve is that all orders with an ordernumber where the last product put in it is older than 8 hours is selected and where I can update the quantity in the products table again. This is for orders that were not finalised.

So my initial query is:

```sql
SELECT ordernumber,
       ProductId,
       OrderDate,
       quantity
FROM ShopCart
where orderdate < DATEADD(hour, -8, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
order by ordernumber
```

But now the problem is that possible products in the shopcart for the same ordernumber are not selected.
I don't want to "empty" a selection of the order...

Comment: FYI, I really recommend using linebreaks and white space when writing code; it makes it far more readable.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. I don't see why this wouldn't give you what you want.

Comment: Has your question been answered?  Are there any issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ordernumber,ProductId,OrderDate,quantity
FROM ShopCart 
WHERE ordernumber IN (SELECT ordernumber 
        FROM ShopCart GROUP BY ordernumber HAVING MAX(OrderDate) < DATEADD(hour, -8, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))
ORDER BY ordernumber
```

Comment: Thanks jason2014, tested it and this works fine to me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below

```
SELECT ordernumber, ProductId, OrderDate, quantity
FROM ShopCart
WHERE ordernumber IN (
    -- ordernumber that all products added more than 8 hours ago.
    SELECT DISTINCT ordernumber
    FROM ShopCart sc
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        -- ordernumber which has product added less than 8 hours ago.
        SELECT 1
        FROM ShopCart
        WHERE ordernumber = sc.ordernumber 
            AND orderdate > DATEADD(hour, -8, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you're looking for something like this.  The first 2 CTE's locate the orders with an item placed in the shopping cart prior to 8 hours ago.  The quantities of the products within those orders are summarized to the ProductId.  Then the Products table is updated to add back the ShopCart quantities.

```
with
cart_cte(ordernumber, ProductId, OrderDate, quantity, rn) as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ordernumber order by OrderDate)
    from ShopCart),
prod_cte(ProductId, sum_quantity) as (
    select ProductId, sum(quantity)
    from cart_cte cc
         join ShopCart sc on cc.ordernumber=sc.ordernumber
    where cc.rn=1
          and cc.orderdate < DATEADD(hour, -8, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
    group by ProductId)
update p
    set quantity=quantity+pc.sum_quantity
from Products p
     join prod_cte pc on p.ProductId=pc.ProductId;
```